# "Fake" Full-screening a browser window (with no edges) so it doesn't take priority & can have other things full-screened over it?

Tags: google-chrome, video, fullscreen, firefox, projector

I'm running a stage show using a projector & Q-lab, and am looking for this solution.

On the projector, I need a browser window full-screened with NO visible edges. The window has interactable elements, needs to remain the "baseline", and can't be seen being minimized.

BUT, we have brief moments where I need to have Qlab project a video over top, and then back to the browser again. When the browser is in a window, this works flawlessly. When the browser is ctrl-option-F full-screened, the video won't overtake it and doesn't display.

The best app I can find still has edges + a bar at the top. I've considered using a secondary zoom-in program to remove this, but it costs $50 and is an extra step I don't want our tech person to deal with.

So- Any leads on an app or code that would "fake" a completely full-screen browser window on Mac?

Thank you!

Comment: if you don't find anything else you can go to system preferences > accessibility > zoom and set a keystroke or gesture (I use CONTROL + 2-Finger  trackpad swipe) to zoom in just enough to hide the system and browser chrome. It's a bit of a kludge for what you are doing but it is worth a shot...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome or firefox, either would work.

Comment: @SteveChambers Unfortunately I need to mouse around between them, and that moves the screen/edges around. There's no built-in way to lock the zoom, sadly. Greatly appreciate your answer though!